# InfoPath 2013 form causes "Server out of memory" error when viewing list item

Tags: 2013, infopath, error, form, sql

I have a rather large (200+ field) InfoPath form on a custom list that is full of drop-downs referencing other lists on the same site, along with some textboxes and checkboxes. There's not much in the way of formatting or rules present, so despite the form being large it is not exactly complicated. When creating a new item the form works fine, and saves the item properly. But when trying to view an item created by this form users receive the following "Server out of memory" error:

[image: Server out of memory]

For reference and the sake of search engines, here is the text description:

```
There is no memory on the server to run your program. Please contact your administrator with this problem.<nativehr>0x8007000e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

I have ensured there are at least 20% memory and processing power available on both the WFE and the SQL server, and even rebooted the WFE to reset all the connections and clear any possible memory leak, but the results are unchanged. The only references I can find to this problem say the SQL database is out of room but I have verified there is plenty of extra space available. Our sysadmin has watched the SQL connections and doesn't see anything odd happen when I trigger the error, and there's no reference to it on the WFE event logs.

What could be causing this?

**Update:** The form has three views with the fields spread across them. In the past I have had weird issues with multiple views mucking up a form so on a hunch I created a copy of the list/form and deleted the two extra views and all related fields. This fixed the issue, however it's not an ideal solution. If anyone could provide insight into an overall fix that would allow me to use the other views I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: possibly a memory leak or infinite loop when creating the item with the form? I would check your InfoPath code, if you have any.

Comment: There's no special code, the form was created strictly with oob controls. Could there still be a leak/loop? How would I check for it?

Comment: How many datasources do you have? Also, How many repeating fields do you have?

Comment: No repeating fields, but there are 18 data sources, all pointing to very small lists in the same site. A good amount of those aren't even used but were created automatically when the field was created, though the fields had their choices switched to another data source and the originals can't be removed apparently.

Comment: why can't they be removed? If you aren't using a data source in InfoPath, it should be removed.

Comment: That's what I thought but I tried deleting them and was denied because they're supposedly still in use. I'll double check all the fields to verify that.

Comment: Okay I removed all the data sources that weren't needed but the symptoms are still the same. I did manage to make a template from the list (though without content, trying that causes an error) to experiment on, but it is showing identical symptoms. Any more ideas?

Comment: how many fields or data connections pull from sharepoint lists?